# Invalid Firefox Executable Error with Selenium: Seeking Solutions for geckodriver and webdriver-manager

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver

I tried to start my driver first like this, as described in the official selenium documentation.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://selenium.dev")
print(driver.title)
```

I put the geckodriver in the same directory as this script and also added the geckodriver to the path.

```
$ geckodriver --version
geckodriver 0.33.0 ( 2023-10-19)
```

However, I got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

I looked for some solutions for this, but they were either targeted towards older selenium versions and it led back to the previous code from the selenium documentation, which did not work for me.

I also tried the webdriver-manager:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("http://selenium.dev")
print(driver.title)
```

However, I got this error.

[image: Error when using webdriver]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with the geckodriver (https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Usage.html#Running-Firefox-in-an-container-based-package). When I used the chromedriver, it worked.